# call and Pass a cURL command through Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex Oracle application . I need to perform some curl requests .
For rest requests, I usually invoke the web server using the method :

```
apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL, p_http_method => Method);
```

But I don't know how to do that for curl? Does it have to be translated to HTTP request ? Is there any specific way to perform cURL requests in Apex oracle ?

Here is the sample of request :

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Authorization: Bearer 
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInRva2VuIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiaWF0Ijox     
NjAzMTg0NTAyLCJleHAiOjE2MDMxODgxMDJ9.Qh1f1NLX2NllAzV_5bi1X_tnslTet0gaolzRWAzWam0" -d '<?xml 
 version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ..........
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there a many lot more parameters in this function. see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1955.

for this request, you must set p_http_headers and p_http_hdr_values in the function call

```
declare
  l_response clob;
  l_http_hdr wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;
  l_http_hdr_val wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;
begin
  l_http_hdr(1) := 'Authorization';
  l_http_hdr_val(1) := 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInRva2VuIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiaWF0Ijox     
NjAzMTg0NTAyLCJleHAiOjE2MDMxODgxMDJ9.Qh1f1NLX2NllAzV_5bi1X_tnslTet0gaolzRWAzWam0';

  l_response := apex_web_services.make_rest_request(
    p_url => <your_url>,
    p_http_method => <http_method>,
    p_body => <your_xml_message_as_clob>,
    -- auth header (in curl -H)
    p_http_header => l_http_hdr,
    p_http_hdr_values => l_http_hdr_val);
  -- do anything with response ...
end;
'''

and use the sql developer to take a look in the package spec. there are also examples for the function call.
```